# count how many files generated with "find" command

Tags: linux

For example, my command was

```
find . -type f -name "script.log" -exec grep "finished without error" {} \;
```

It generates hundreds of lines of output. How do I calculate how many files are found?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find the number of all .txt files in a directory and all sub directories using specifically the find command and the wc command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40295297/how-do-i-find-the-number-of-all-txt-files-in-a-directory-and-all-sub-directorie)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the output of find to the "word count" programm `wc`

```
find . -type f -name "script.log" -exec grep "finished without error" {} \;| wc -l
```

`wc -l` writes the number of lines to stdout.